# Remove empty commas in the string in sql server

Tags: replace

I want to remove blank values commas(first,last and consecutive empty commas) in the below table.My table contains below values

```
  x
 ---    
 ,1,2,3,
 4,5,6
 7,8,,,9
 ,10,11
```

I want the below result.

```
O/P
---
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11

CREATE TYPE TableVariable AS TABLE
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    field_ids        INT,
    value    VARCHAR(MAX)
)

inserting values in this type

DECLARE @DepartmentTVP AS TableVariable;
insert into  @DepartmentTVP values(1994,',85574,,,85538,')

when i select from this type i want to remove this commas(first,last and consecutive commas in the value)
```

Comment: Your table design is beyond not optimal.  The best solution would be to do away with that CSV data entirely.  You are seeing the hassle with maintaining such data.

Comment: This is not actual table values.This type of values are passed to stored procedure  from front end.I want to remove this blank values commas.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: please check in the above posting.I added my requirement.created user defined type and inserting values into this type.When i select values from this type.i want to remove the commas.

Comment: i hope this will work for my requirement.

create table xyz(x varchar(max))
insert into xyz values('1,2,3')
insert into xyz values(',4,5,6,')
insert into xyz values(',7,8,9')
insert into xyz values('10,11,12,')
insert into xyz values('13,14,,15,')
SELECT Replace(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(x, ',', ' '))), ' ', ','),',,',',') FROM xyz